# Dual Screen Application C/Linux

Tags: c, linux

I have a stable application written in C using GTK. I have a client who would like us to provide him with a version of the application that runs in dual-screen mode. I'm investigating options for having the application GUI being split in to two different windows and ultimately appear on two separate screens. Any leads on where I can get started are appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: google gtk multiscreen

Comment: Most Xorg graphics drivers provide a single screen across multiple displays. Then, you only need to set the main window geometries at startup. I'd personally like a menu entry that simply said *"Save window locations"* or similar, which causes the default geometries to be set *if the desktop is at least as large when the locations were saved*; otherwise the window geometries are left as default (up to window manager). That avoids the case where disconnecting one display makes one window inaccessible.